# From long to wide format with the same id

Tags: r

As the initial dataframe:

```
structure(list(text = c("test", "text", "section", "2", "sending"
), id = c(32, 32, 41, 41, 41)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

How is it possible to make from long to wide format using the same id to put in the same row the content of text column separated by space?

Example output:

```
id text
32 test text
41 section 2 sending
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(text = paste(text, collapse = " ")) %>%
  slice(1)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
  text                 id
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 test text            32
2 section 2 sending    41
```

Comment: You can use `summarise(text = paste(text, collapse = " "))` instead of mutate + slice

Answer (score 2):

You can `aggregate` from the `{stats}` package and use `paste` as your aggregating function:

```r
aggregate(text ~ id, FUN = paste, collapse = " ", data = df)

#>   id              text
#> 1 32         test text
#> 2 41 section 2 sending
```